# Request header is too large

Tags: http, tomcat, headers

I am getting this entry in my Tomcat 8.5 stderr log:

> 16-Jan-2018 02:38:04.089 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2]
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP
>   request header  Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing
>   errors will be logged at DEBUG level. 
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeaders(Http11InputBuffer.java:571)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:683)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1441)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

It occurs when the size of the request body is approx. 8kb.

How can I get more detail about this error?  Is there a way I can view the header?

Comment: Welcome to [su]! The [tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/index.html) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

There was no body in the request, everything was in the header

With lots of web searching I learned that Tomcat's default maximum header size is 8192 bytes.  I added a "maxHttpHeaderSize="9216" to the Connector definition in server.xml.  Problem solved.